# How to select different category data from in one colum?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have a table in my database named `product`, with columns `name` `price`, and `category`, and there are 6 items which are related to 2 main categories. Let's say:

```
+----------+-------+-----------+
|  name    | price |  category |
+----------+-------+-----------+
|  mango   |  $58  |  fruits   |
|  avocado |  $74  |  fruits   |
|  apple   |  $20  |  fruits   |
|  carrot  |  $35  | vegetable |
|  onions  |  $40  | vegetable |
+----------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to make 2 `JComboBox`, firstly select a category and then another `JComboBox` to load all related names (if I select `fruit`, then other `JComboBox` will show all the fruit items).

Here's my code which selects all `name` from database and loads it to a combo box.

```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            DBconnector db =  new DBconnector();
            con=  db.connect();
            String qr = "SELECT name FROM product";
            PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(qr);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(qr);

            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                //add group list to the arraylist
                list.add(name);
            }
            rs.close();

            //Populate the comboBox
            if(!list.isEmpty()){
            DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());
            combItems.setModel(model);
            }else{
                System.out.println("List is empty...");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Data not retrieved");
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        return list;
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `select name from product where category = ?`??  You might like to narrow down your question to which part you are having trouble with.  Using the combo boxes; writing the query; something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main options: After the user selects category, run the query with a where clause using the selected category; or create a map from category to list of names then use that to create your second combobox.

The second option would look something like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
while(rs.next()){
    List<String> namesForCategory = categoryMap.getOrDefault(rs.getString("category"), new ArrayList<>());
    namesForCategory.add(rs.getString("name"));
    categoryMap.put(rs.getString("category"), namesForCategory);
}
```

Now after the category is selected you can get the list of names with `categoryMap.get(name)`.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the where clause option and distinct and shows how to connect the two comboboxes with item listener:

```
            JFrame frm = new JFrame();
            JComboBox catBox = new JComboBox();
            final Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample","app","app");
            String getcatsQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT category from PRODUCT";
            PreparedStatement getcatsStatement = con.prepareStatement(getcatsQuery);
            ResultSet rs = getcatsStatement.executeQuery();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String cat = rs.getString("category");
                //add group list to the arraylist
                list.add(cat);
            }
            rs.close();
            System.out.println("list = " + list);
            DefaultComboBoxModel catsModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());
            catBox.setModel(catsModel);
            final JComboBox prodBox = new JComboBox();
            prodBox.addItem("             ");
            catBox.addItemListener(e -> {
                try {
                    String getprodsQuery = "SELECT name from PRODUCT where category=?";
                    PreparedStatement getprodsStatement = con.prepareStatement(getprodsQuery);
                    getprodsStatement.setString(1, catBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    ResultSet rs2 = getprodsStatement.executeQuery();
                    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    while (rs2.next()) {
                        String name = rs2.getString("name");
                        //add group list to the arraylist
                        list2.add(name);
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    DefaultComboBoxModel prodsModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list2.toArray());
                    prodBox.setModel(prodsModel);

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            catBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
            frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frm.add(catBox);
            frm.add(prodBox);
            frm.pack();
            frm.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Great Work Bro Its Working Thnkx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this `query`:

```
String qr = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE category";
```

I think you're having trouble in that line.